# How to post reviews on apps.ubuntu.com?

Tags: software-center

I cannot seem to figure out where's the option to log in or something on apps.ubuntu.com in order to be able to add a review to a program.

How do I post reviews using this web-interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot post reviews directly on the web site. You can only post reviews from within the `software-center` application, and only on packages which you currently have installed.

Comment: But surprisingly it are not the reviews from the software center which are displayed in the Ubuntu apps directory.

Comment: The web site is displaying reviews in all languages. The application only displays reviews in your locale, by default.

Comment: I was thinking so too but sadly it is not the case. See e.g. **jp2a** 0 reviews but 3 in USC, **guayadeque** 3 reviews but many pages in USC, **blender** many reviews both but all different and Chinese in the USC too... there is absolutely no pattern to this.

Comment: After some research, and with different setting on which reviews to display in USC I found that indeed the reviews on the app site do come from user reviews submitted through the USC. Still, the criteria for which reviews will be displayed on the web site remain rather obscure.